# Ui bootstrap typeahead footer "Show More" in AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

If include typeAhead in my project with 15 results max and I added a footer with "Show More" as text.

[image]

But when I click on the footer, there is always the last item of the result which is selected, so when I click on "Show More" it select the last item and put it in the typeAhead.

Here is my custom template

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="typeahead-item.html">
        <div class="typeahead-group-header" ng-if="match.model.firstInGroup">{{match.model.objectType}}</div>
        <a>
            {{match.label}}
        </a>

        <div class="typeahead-group-footer" ng-show="index == 14"><a href="/#!/showmore?objecttype={{match.model.objectType}}" ng-click="selected=''">Show More</a></div>       

</script>
```

So when I click on show more I don't want an item to be selected,